# When are dot operators required?

Tags: java, methods

When calling a method, I get that you have to use `instanceName.method()` or `className.method()`. However, in some cases the `instanceName` or `className` is omitted in the code and just `method()` is written.

Programming language is Java.  Just covering this for the AP Computer Science test and I have relatively limited knowledge of coding outside of the parameters of the course so a easy to understand explanation would be greatly appreciated.

My book says something about client programs but I'm not exactly sure what it means (both in general and about client programs specifically).

Comment: When you calling the method from same class or you calling an inherited method you don't need a dot operator.

Comment: his are very Basics. you should know it before starting a test

Comment: Code inside class `A` can refer to class `A`'s static methods and fields without putting `A.` in front. (Or to static methods and fields in classes that `A` inherits from.) Code in an instance method can refer to this instance's fields and methods by just the name without `this.` in front (including fields and methods that `this` inherits from base classes).

Answer (score 0):

I'll put my explanation as simply as possible - Usually you would use `instanceName.method()` when trying to effect the variables within a class. For example a "Cat" object, you could make a cat - `Cat catOne = new Cat()` and then use its methods `catOne.setName("Kitty");`. This will set this objects name to "Kitty", leaving all other cat objects with the ability to have their own unique name.

Using `className.method()` is done when using a static method within a class, eg `public static int method()`, and then using it in another class. This does not require you to instantiate an object for that class, and can use them willingly. For example, having a class called `MathConstants` and using something like `MathConstants.getPi()` ( Sorry for the crude example ).

When methods are called like `methodName()` , this means that the method is located within the class itself. Usually we use `this` , as in `this.methodName()`, but just using `methodName()` is okay.

Hope that is easy to understand

Comment: Yeah that makes a lot of sense.  Thanks!

Comment: @JeffreyKim no problem! Don't forget to up-vote answer ;) The grind for rep is real